# Java Core file. Only seeing Java code. Is it a JVM issue?

Tags: java

Usually when running the "where" command against a Java core file there is usually some reference to one of my function calls.

Here, there doesn't appear to be any reference to any of my calls. The stack appears to only contain Java

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000147f7b43770f in raise () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000147f7b421b25 in abort () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000147f7a075017 in os::abort(bool, void*, void const*) [clone .cold.42] () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x0000147f7ad9c47c in VMError::report_and_die(int, char const*, char const*, __va_list_tag*, Thread*, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, int, unsigned long) ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x0000147f7ad9cfd1 in VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, ...) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x0000147f7ad9d012 in VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, void*, void*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#6  0x0000147f7ac39ad2 in JVM_handle_linux_signal () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#7  <signal handler called>
#8  0x0000147f7a991a6c in markWord::displaced_mark_helper() const () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#9  0x0000147f7a585f69 in G1ParScanThreadState::steal_and_trim_queue(GenericTaskQueueSet<OverflowTaskQueue<ScannerTask, (MEMFLAGS)5, 131072u>, (MEMFLAGS)5>*) ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#10 0x0000147f7a539e73 in G1ParEvacuateFollowersClosure::do_void() () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#11 0x0000147f7a53df86 in G1EvacuateRegionsTask::evacuate_live_objects(G1ParScanThreadState*, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#12 0x0000147f7a53b7bb in G1EvacuateRegionsBaseTask::work(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#13 0x0000147f7adcc9f4 in GangWorker::loop() () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#14 0x0000147f7adcca52 in GangWorker::run() () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#15 0x0000147f7ad20d61 in Thread::call_run() () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#16 0x0000147f7aa524a9 in thread_native_entry(Thread*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so
#17 0x0000147f7b9ce2de in start_thread () from /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
#18 0x0000147f7b4fbe83 in clone () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
```

In the associated dump file is the following :

```
---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xbootclasspath/a:/lib/corba-stub.jar:/lib/jacorb.jar:/usr/java/latest/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/latest/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/latest/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/latest/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/latest/lib/jsse.jar -Djava.library.path=/xalocal/L/lib/sb:/xalocal/L/lib/es:/opt/CARKaim/sdk -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB.Singleton -Xverify:none -Xms512M -Xmx2G  MyApp

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6342 CPU @ 2.80GHz, 4 cores, 11G, Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa)
Time: Tue Nov 21 07:54:10 2023 CST elapsed time: 32.259012 seconds (0d 0h 0m 32s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000147f38005070):  GCTaskThread "GC Thread#1" [stack: 0x0000147f4800a000,0x0000147f4810a000] [id=972621]

Stack: [0x0000147f4800a000,0x0000147f4810a000],  sp=0x0000147f48108b88,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xb6fa6c]  markWord::displaced_mark_helper() const+0x1c
V  [libjvm.so+0x717e73]  G1ParEvacuateFollowersClosure::do_void()+0xf3
V  [libjvm.so+0x71bf86]  G1EvacuateRegionsTask::evacuate_live_objects(G1ParScanThreadState*, unsigned int)+0x96
V  [libjvm.so+0x7197bb]  G1EvacuateRegionsBaseTask::work(unsigned int)+0xab
V  [libjvm.so+0xfaa9f4]  GangWorker::loop()+0x74
V  [libjvm.so+0xfaaa52]
V  [libjvm.so+0xefed61]  Thread::call_run()+0x71
V  [libjvm.so+0xc304a9]  thread_native_entry(Thread*)+0xe9




siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000014

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000014 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000009c4997f8 is an oop: dir.objects.MyObject1
{0x000000009c4997f8} - klass: 'dir/objects/MyObject1'
 - ---- fields (total size 8 words):
 - public 'field1' 'I' @12  0
 - public 'field2' 'I' @16  4
 - public 'field3' 'I' @20  8
 - public 'field4' 'I' @24  9
 - public 'field5' 'I' @28  10 (a)
 - public 'field6' 'I' @32  11 (b)
 - public 'field7' 'I' @36  12 (c)
 - public 'field8' 'I' @40  13 (d)
 - public 'field9' 'I' @44  17 (11)
 - public 'field10' 'I' @48  0
 - public 'field11' 'I' @52  0
 - public 'field12' 'I' @56  0
RCX=0x0 is NULL
RDX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000147f48108b88 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000147f7a585f69 | 69 5f 58 7a 7f 14 00 00
RBP=0x0000147f48108c40 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000147f48108d00 | 00 8d 10 48 7f 14 00 00
RSI=0x0000147f7b375320: <offset 0x0000000001553320> in /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.7.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64/lib/server/libjvm.so at 0x0000147f79e22000
RDI=0x0000147f48108c00 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000000000000014 | 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
R8 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000dc00000375 is an unknown value
R10=0x0 is NULL
R11=0x000000008cac381d is pointing into object: dir.objects.MyObject2
{0x000000008cac3798} - klass: 'dir/objects/MyObject2'
 - ---- fields (total size 26 words):
 - private 'field1' 'I' @12  360 (168)
 - private 'field2' 'J' @16  1700574836289 (f228b641 18b)
 - private 'field3' 'J' @24  1700574849269 (f228e8f5 18b)
 - private 'field4' 'J' @32  0 (0 0)
 - private volatile 'field5' 'J' @40  1700574849269 (f228e8f5 18b)
 - private 'field6' 'I' @48  0
 - private 'field7' 'I' @52  3
 - private 'field8' 'I' @56  0
 - private 'field9' 'I' @60  6
 - private 'field10' 'Z' @64  true
 - private 'field11' 'Z' @65  false
 - private 'field12' 'Z' @66  false
 - private 'field13' 'Z' @67  false
 - private 'field14' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @68  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008cac3868} (8cac3868)
 - private 'field15' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @72  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008cac3878} (8cac3878)
 - private 'field16' 'Ldir/objects/Timer;' @76  a 'dir/objects/Timer'{0x000000008cac3888} (8cac3888)
 - private 'field17' 'Ldir/objects/Timer;' @80  a 'dir/objects/Timer'{0x000000008cac3940} (8cac3940)
 - private 'field18' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @84  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008cac39f8} (8cac39f8)
 - private 'field19' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @88  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008c8b2ca0} (8c8b2ca0)
 - private 'field20' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @92  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008c8b2ce0} (8c8b2ce0)
 - private 'field21' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @96  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008c670578} (8c670578)
 - private 'field22' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @100  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008c6705a8} (8c6705a8)
 - private 'field23' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @104  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008b542058} (8b542058)
 - private 'field24' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @108  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008b542028} (8b542028)
 - private 'field25' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @112  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008b541ff8} (8b541ff8)
 - private 'field26' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @116  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008b541fc8} (8b541fc8)
 - private 'field27' 'Ljava/util/Vector;' @120  a 'java/util/Vector'{0x000000008b541520} (8b541520)
 - private 'field28' 'Ljava/util/Vector;' @124  a 'java/util/Vector'{0x000000008b5413d0} (8b5413d0)
 - private 'field29' 'Ljava/util/Vector;' @128  a 'java/util/Vector'{0x000000008b541378} (8b541378)
 - private 'field30' 'Ldir/objects/MyObject1;' @132  a 'dir/objects/MyObject1'{0x000000009c4997f8} (9c4997f8)
 - private 'field31' 'Ljava/util/Vector;' @136  a 'java/util/Vector'{0x000000008b66e400} (8b66e400)
 - private 'field32' 'Ljava/util/Vector;' @140  a 'java/util/Vector'{0x000000008b66def0} (8b66def0)
 - private 'field33' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @144  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b66dee0} (8b66dee0)
 - private 'field34' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @148  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b66ded0} (8b66ded0)
 - private 'field35' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @152  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b66dec0} (8b66dec0)
 - private 'field36' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @156  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b66deb0} (8b66deb0)
 - private 'field37' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @160  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b66dea0} (8b66dea0)
 - private 'field38' 'Ljava/util/Hashtable;' @164  a 'java/util/Hashtable'{0x000000008b66de30} (8b66de30)
 - private 'field39' 'Ljava/util/Vector;' @168  a 'java/util/Vector'{0x000000008b66ddd8} (8b66ddd8)
 - private 'field40' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @172  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b66ddc8} (8b66ddc8)
 - private 'field41' 'Ljava/lang/Thread;' @176  NULL (0)
 - private 'field42' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @180  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b66ddb8} (8b66ddb8)
 - private 'field43' 'Ljava/util/HashMap;' @184  a 'java/util/HashMap'{0x000000008b66dd78} (8b66dd78)
 - private 'field44' 'Ljava/lang/Object;' @188  a 'java/lang/Object'{0x000000008b376740} (8b376740)
 - private 'field45' 'Ljava/util/Map;' @192  a 'java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap'{0x000000008b3766f0} (8b3766f0)
 - private 'field46' 'Ljava/util/Map;' @196  a 'java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap'{0x000000008b3766a0} (8b3766a0)
 - private 'field47' 'Ljava/util/Map;' @200  a 'java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap'{0x000000008b376538} (8b376538)
 - private 'field48' 'Ljava/util/Map;' @204  a 'java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap'{0x000000008b3764e8} (8b3764e8)
R12=0x0000000000000008 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000147f00140000 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000147f7b2c4f20 | 20 4f 2c 7b 7f 14 00 00
R14=0x0000147f74053e90 points into unknown readable memory: 0x0000147f7b2c4130 | 30 41 2c 7b 7f 14 00 00
R15=0x00000000834e0b5f points into unknown readable memory: 00


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000014, RBX=0x000000009c4997f8, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000001
RSP=0x0000147f48108b88, RBP=0x0000147f48108c40, RSI=0x0000147f7b375320, RDI=0x0000147f48108c00
R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x000000dc00000375, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000008cac381d
R12=0x0000000000000008, R13=0x0000147f00140000, R14=0x0000147f74053e90, R15=0x00000000834e0b5f
RIP=0x0000147f7a991a6c, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

Although it is loading dir.objects.MyObject1 and dir.objects.MyObject2, they both seem to have issues.
But since it didn't fail after the first set of errors, it made it appear as though it was not critical.

Do you see anything that is specific to the JVM that may be a possible issue?

Is there anything obvious I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

Seems an issue related to garbage collection. The last frames are related to the G1 GC algorithm:

```
V  [libjvm.so+0xb6fa6c]  markWord::displaced_mark_helper() const+0x1c
V  [libjvm.so+0x717e73]  G1ParEvacuateFollowersClosure::do_void()+0xf3
V  [libjvm.so+0x71bf86]  G1EvacuateRegionsTask::evacuate_live_objects(G1ParScanThreadState*, unsigned int)+0x96
V  [libjvm.so+0x7197bb]  G1EvacuateRegionsBaseTask::work(unsigned int)+0xab
```

It could be related to JVM bug [JDK-8273108](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8273108) or [JDK-8313658](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8313658.).

I'm not sure if the CORBA libraries used could be a factor.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35298735)

Comment: I was answering directly to the OP question however I acknowledge it was missing details. I added an explanation and links.